# Instr function currency

Tags: ms-access-2007

I'm trying to return a currency value from a large memo field of text, however I have a lot of dirty data eg: "$ $12,500"

> InStr(1,[Case Activity Content],"$")

Doesn't work in the above case. For some reason

> InStr(1,[Case Activity Content],"$#")
>   InStr(1,[Case Activity Content],"$[1234567890]")

all fail. Anyone know how to make the InStr pick up the second $?

Answer (score 0):

You can use *Split*:

```
DollarArray = Split([YourMemo], "$")

' Now loop DollarArray for valid entries.
' DollarArray(2) will hold: "12,500"
```

Comment: Thanks Gustav!   However I am not familiar with VBA at this stage. 
Can it be done with Access' internal functions?

Comment: Well, _Split_ is an internal function, but you can't run loops in expressions.